# The return type 'List<dynamic>' isn't a 'List<Entry>', as required by the closure's context

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class FirestoreService {
  FirebaseFirestore _db  = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  //Get Entries
  Stream<List<Entry>> getEntries() {
    return _db
        .collection('entries')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => Entry.fromJson(doc.data()))
        .toList());
  }


  //Create


  //Update



  //Delete


}
```

Hi, this is my code Im getting this error which says the return type List(dynamic) isn't a List(Entry), as required by the closures's context. How to rectify this?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried providing `map` with a type argument? `.map<Entry>((doc) => Entry.fromJson(doc.data()))`

Comment: replace Entry with dynamic

Comment: I did the exact same thing. Now it says the method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the type 'Entry'. @RaulSauco

Comment: @p2kr sorry I could not follow what you meant. Could you elaborate where should I replace Entry with dynamic

Comment: replace List<Entry> with List<dynamic>

Comment: @p2kr I replaced List<Entry> with List<dynamic> . Now it says the method fromJson isn't defined for the type Entry

Comment: why have you dart:html imported?

Comment: @ShauryaKohli I realized that comment should have been an answer, if it helped you consider [marking it accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and/or [up-voting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `map` some help by providing a type:

```dart
.map<Entry>((doc) => Entry.fromJson(doc.data()))
```

The whole method would be:

```dart
//Get Entries
Stream<List<Entry>> getEntries() {
  return _db
    .collection('entries')
    .snapshots()
    .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
    .map<Entry>((doc) => Entry.fromJson(doc.data()))
    .toList());
}
```

Your method returns a `List<Entry>` but the return expression returns a `List<dynamic>` unless you explicitly cast the result to `Entry`.

Adding the type should solve the problem.